# Extracting Outlook recipient addresses

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have two columns with headers To and Cc.

I need to extract To and Cc email addresses, not name, into the Excel file from Outlook.

```vb
Sub ExportOutlookInfo()
Dim o As Outlook.Application
Set o = New Outlook.Application
Dim ons As Outlook.Namespace
Set ons = o.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Dim omail As Outlook.MailItem
Set omail = o.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Dim i As Long
Dim olRecip As Outlook.Recipient
Dim olRecipAddress As String
Dim SENT_FLDR As MAPIFolder
Dim Items As Outlook.Items
Set SENT_FLDR = ons.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
Set Items = SENT_FLDR.Items
Dim recp As Outlook.Application

For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
    DoEvents
    For Each olRecip In Items(i).Recipients
        Debug.Print olRecip.Address
    Next olRecip
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Recipients` property of the `MailItem` class to get recipient email addresses. The [Using Outlook Recipient and Recipients collection – guide for developers](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2014/09/18/using-outlook-recipients-collection/) article explains how to deal with recipients. If you need to get the recipient's email address you may use the following sequence of calls:

```
Recipient.AddressEntry.Address
```

The `Address` property of the `AddressEntry` class returns a string representing the e-mail address of the `AddressEntry`.

Also you may find the [GetExchangeUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff869721.aspx) method of the `AddressEntry` class which returns an [ExchangeUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff866281.aspx) object that represents the AddressEntry if the AddressEntry belongs to an Exchange `AddressList` object such as the Global Address List (GAL) and corresponds to an Exchange user. The `ExchangeUser` class provides the [PrimarySmtpAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff862991.aspx) property which I suppose you are looking for. Read more about converting email address in the [HowTo: Convert Exchange-based email address into SMTP email address](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2009/05/08/outlook-exchange-email-address-smtp/) article.

There is another way of getting SMTP addresses of the recipients. The following `GetSMTPAddressForRecipients` method takes a `MailItem` as an input argument and then displays the SMTP address of each recipient for that mail item. The method first retrieves the `Recipients` collection that represents the set of recipients specified for the mail item. For each `Recipient` in that `Recipients` collection, the method then obtains the `PropertyAccessor` object that corresponds to that `Recipient` object, and uses the `PropertyAccessor` to get the value of the MAPI property `https://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E`, that maps to the SMTP address of the recipient.

```
Sub GetSMTPAddressForRecipients(mail As Outlook.MailItem) 
    Dim recips As Outlook.Recipients 
    Dim recip As Outlook.Recipient 
    Dim pa As Outlook.PropertyAccessor 
    Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = _ 
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E" 
    Set recips = mail.Recipients 
    For Each recip In recips 
        Set pa = recip.PropertyAccessor 
        Debug.Print recip.name & " SMTP=" _ 
           & pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS) 
    Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your inputs.
Actually, using this method but getting error as - /o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=09860f1d823e46808c54c64c02ab125c-San

Comment: This is not an error, this is Exchange based email address format, see [HowTo: Convert Exchange-based email address into SMTP email address](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2009/05/08/outlook-exchange-email-address-smtp/) how to convert it to the SMTP format.

Comment: Thank you for your support.. Now, Issue resolved

Comment: It makes sense to mark the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are accessing the `To` and `CC` properties (which contain `;` separated lists of display names which may or may not contain email addresses), you need to extract the addresses one at a time - loop through the `MailItem.Recipients` collection, then for each `Recipient` object, check the `Recipient.Type` property (can be `olTo`, `olCC`, `olBCC`). You can then read the `Recipient.Address` property.

Note that for Exchange recipients (address type of `"EX"` instead of `"SMTP"`), you will end up with EX addresses. If you always want an SMTP address, check that you have the right address type by reading the `PR_ADDRTYPE` (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3002001F"`) MAPI property using `Recipient.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`. If it is "SMTP", `Recipient.Address` property is all you need. If it is "EX", try to read the `PR_SMTP_ADDRESS` MAPI property (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001F"`). If it is missing, your last resort will be `Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress` (expensive and can raise an error).

Comment: Thank you for your support! Issue resolved

Comment: If the reply answers your question, please mark it as such. Thanks!